# "random does not name a type " error even though definition included

Tags: c++, compilation, forward-declaration

I have been looking on SO for an answer to a compilation error message that I am running into, but I seems that my use case is much simpler, and that this problem shouldn't even be there. I am certainly missing something very trivial, and would appreciate the help to locate the error.

I have the following snippets of code.

```
/*file rand.h*/

class random{
// definition of class 
};
```

and another file called method.h

```
/* file method.h*/

#include "rand.h"

/* lots of stuff...many lines */
class method{
    random rng;
};
```

and finally a cpp file main.cpp

```
#include "method.h"
int main(){
    method METHOD;
    return 0;
}
```

On compilation, I get the error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
method.h:40:5: error: ‘random’ does not name a type
     random rng;
```

## Partial Code Dump

method.h

```
#ifndef METHOD
#define METHOD

#include "rand.h"

class node
{
//stuff
};

// stuff


template<class T>
class ssa
{
public:
    T& model;
    random rng;
};
```

rand.h

```
#ifndef RAND_H
#define RAND_H

#include "mtrand.h"
#include <cmath>

class random : public MTRand {

    public:

    MTRand rng;

    random(){};
    random(unsigned long seed){rng.seed(seed);};
    void seed(unsigned long _seed){
        rng.seed(_seed);
    }
    double exp(double theta){
        double inv_mean = 1.0/theta;
        double u = rng();
        return std::log(1 - u)/(-inv_mean);
    }
    double uniform(){
        return rng();
    }

};

#endif
```

model.h is included in the main file.

Compilation happens with the command
    `g++ -c -fPIC main.cpp -o main.o`

Comment: The code you show should work. The problem is likely in the code you haven't shown. My educated guess is circular #includes.

Comment: Have you tried compiling just these snippets?  Incidentally you're missing a semicolon after your `method` class, so that alone would prevent these snippets from compiling.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I have looked at the code I haven't shown fairly carefully, and I am certain there are no circular includes. However, how do I present that information without dumping the entire code here?

Comment: @CCG: You shouldn't present that information here.  You should try compiling just the relevant snippets presented here.  That will allow you to determine whether the problem is with this code, or with the code you haven't shown.

Comment: Start with your problem.  Make 2 copies of it (original, and iteration).  Now guess what you think is not relevant to your problem.  Delete that part.  Recompile, and confirm your problem is the first error encountered.  Make a copy of this revision.  Delete more stuff that you don't think is related.  Test.  If deleting some code gets it wrong, backup to your most recent backup (confirm  problem still occurs with it!), then delete other stuff.  Delete low hanging fruit first: method bodies first (linker errors only are ok!), .cpp files, data you never interact with, etc.

Comment: @CCG reduce your code to a minimal example that shows the problem, and paste it in. [see here for more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Yakk use version control! `git checkout -b mcve` , make the example, check it shows the problem, post it, switch back to your main branch

Comment: @CCG your update does `#include "mtrand.h"`. You need to either show the full contents of `mtrand.h`, or edit your code to not require this include (and verify that you still get the problem)

Comment: I wonder if some of your include guards are incorrect. (You're  missing the `#endif` in `method.h`, but I don' think that's the problem.) Also, there's a POSIX function called `random()`, declared in `<stdlib.h>`; could you have a conflict with that? What happens if you change the name of your `random` class?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Your guess appears to be correct. Changing the name of the class from `random` to `Random` has made that error go away.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Answers should be posted as answers, not included in the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson No problem on rolling back the edit. I have changed the title of the post to "random does not name a type" because it turns out that the name of the class was the main problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a POSIX function called `random`, declared in `<stdlib.h>`. It appears that your class name `random` conflicts with that.

The simplest solution is to change the name of the class (you said in a comment that that worked).

Since the `random()` function is defined by POSIX but not by ISO C, and is declared in a C standard header, you could also invoke the compiler in a strict ISO conforming mode. If you're using gcc, `gcc -std=cNN` should work, where `NN` is one of `90`, `99`, or `11`. But that would mean you can't use POSIX-specific functions, which may or may not be a problem.

Wrapping the classes in a namespace is probably a cleaner solution (thanks to Alexis Wilke for the suggestion).

Comment: I think he should add a namespace around all of his classes. That would most certainly solve the problem without having to rename the class itself (obviously, it is a renaming since it is now `<namespace>::random`, but it is closer to proper C++.)